# Photoshop image manipulation to round stand alone image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

In Photoshop I just learned to use the create clipping mask feature to create a round image for example.  The image needs to be able to be uploaded into an email design tool that I have to use (it is for work).  The trouble is when I saved it and uploaded it, the square canvas that it was on while I was creating it turned white and remained as a background.  It needs to be a freestanding round image.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Cai please leave answers as answers

Answer (score 1):

Images are inherently rectilinear. To be able to save a circle, the area around the circle needs to be transparent. There are a few file formats that support transparency that I will list below. Which format you choose will depend on the complexity of your image and the amount of compression you find acceptable

**png or png24**

Png is a lossless image format that supports transparency. Lossless meaning that you will not loose any detail in your image from compression. Png tends to lead to larger file sizes as it does not compress the image very much. If you are using a large image you might want to try a different format, especially if you are using this in an email and the load time for the image might suffer

**png-8**

Png 8 is another image format that supports transparency. It is named png-8 as it only supports 8 bits of color information which means that an image in this format can only have 256 colors. This format is good for simpler images and line drawings or images with a lot of solid color. If you have an image with more than 256 colors, Photoshop will automatically convert it into 256 colors. **note** not all browsers and email clients support png-8

**gif**

Gif is very similar to png-8. Pretty much does the same thing. I find that png-8 does a little bit better job of preserving details so I usually only use gif if I need something animated or am using an image where png-8 isn't supported